# Firebase does not work well with arrays: should I reformat my json? or find another database service? Recommendations?

Tags: json, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I've been using a json data that looks like this

```
entirelog : [{
        "date": "22-5-2020",
        "meals": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "egg",
            "imageurl": "something",
            "protein": 1,
            "carbohydrate": 2,
            "fat": 3
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "rice",
            "imageurl": "something",
            "protein": 11,
            "carbohydrate": 12,
            "fat": 2
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "date": "23-5-2020",
        "meals": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "hamburger",
            "imageurl": "something",
            "protein": 111,
            "carbohydrate": 222,
            "fat": 8
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "peanuts",
            "imageurl": "something",
            "protein": 333,
            "carbohydrate": 444,
            "fat": 2
          }
        ]
```

However, when I retrieve this data from firebase, it doesn't get accessed well. As the passed value adds all the unnecessary words like

```
Array [
  Object {
    "date": "23-5-2020",
    "meals": Array [
      Object {
        "carbohydrate": 2,
        "fat": 3,
        "id": 1,
        "imageurl": "something",
        "name": "egg",
        "protein": 1,
      },
      Object {
        "carbohydrate": 12,
        "fat": 2,
        "id": 2,
        "imageurl": "something",
        "name": "rice",
        "protein": 11,
      },
    ],
  },
  Object {
    "date": "24-5-2020",
    "meals": Array [
      Object {
        "carbohydrate": 222,
        "fat": 8,
        "id": 1,
        "imageurl": "something",
        "name": "hamburger",
        "protein": 111,
      },
      Object {
        "carbohydrate": 444,
        "fat": 2,
        "id": 2,
        "imageurl": "something",
        "name": "peanuts",
        "protein": 333,
      },
    ],
  },
  Object {
    "date": "25-5-2020",
    "meals": Array [
      Object {
        "carbohydrate": 2222,
        "fat": 8,
        "id": 1,
        "imageurl": "something",
        "name": "noodles",
        "protein": 1111,
      },
      Object {
        "carbohydrate": 4444,
        "fat": 2,
        "id": 2,
        "imageurl": "something",
        "name": "drink",
        "protein": 3333,
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

I've been thinking if I should either reformat the json array to only include {}, or either find a database service that can deal with arrays. It'd be better to find a database service because I would have to change how the original json data gets accessed in all other parts of my code. But, it might be better to reformat my json data if firebase if far superior than other services. Please let me know your thoughts.

This is an image of what my json object looks like in firebase. Would you recommend me to change the formatting, or look for another database that can deal with arrays like this.

[image]

Comment: Are you using the Real Time Database or Firestore? Can you provide sample of what's stored in Firebase as your data doesn't *look* like an array that's stored in Firebase, nor does it look like it needs to be stored as an array. Array's have consecutive numerical indexes.

Comment: "when I retrieve this data from firebase, it doesn't get accessed well" Please edit your question to include the minimal code with which we can reproduce that. "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: I've updated the post by adding what my data looks like in firesbase. Hope this helps Jay. Let me know if you need more material.

Comment: Please refer to @FrankvanPuffelen comment above as without knowing what the issue actually is, we won't be able to answer. That is an array, which could potentially be avoided but we need to see your code and an explanation of the issue and also what your desired outcome is. Also, it’s a good idea to include code and structures as *text*, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure.